How to clear the receive buffer in a serial bus (SERDEV) kernel driver
I'm writing a very simple linux kernel driver for my serial keyboard, employing serdev. The  driver works and the function
static size_t serdev_keyboard_recv(struct serdev_device *serdev, 
                             const unsigned char *buffer, size_t count) {
        printk("serdev_keyboard: Received byte %d, count %ld \n", buffer[count-1], count);
        return 0;
    }

shows the count and last byte sent (each message is only one byte from the keyboard).
The function is invoked as the receive_buf as:
static const struct serdev_device_ops serdev_keyboard_ops = {
    .receive_buf = serdev_keyboard_recv,
};

But it seems like the buffer saturates at 512 bytes. How can I tell the driver to drain the buffer when it's full, or just simply every time the receive_buf callback is executed?

We really need to see your source code. But, your userspace app can do: tcflush see: https://linux.die.net/man/3/tcdrain

@CraigEstey, it looks like he has an issue in the posted code. How does your advice fix this?

Hint: When you see a function prototype which may return only non-negative values, think about it. @CraigEstey note this.

@0andriy Right, I wonder about my return function too. The code is a replica of this one, except for the .receive_buf callback. In that example, the callback returns serdev_device_write_buf(serdev, buffer, size). To get starting with my keyboard driver, I jremoved the serdev_device_write_buf() and returned just 0... the original code works as I expect (received buffer is flushed/restarted every character sent). Now I wonder if the write_buf function is responsible for that.

Ok, now it is working as expected. Following the hints from @Oandriy, the callback .receive_buf is set now to return the size of the data received. So the next interrupt is starting the buffer from zero.
I would probably need to implement a return more elaborated, checking if the callback data size is larger than the buffer size... but considering that my keyboard is simply sending 1 byte is not that important.
Thanks!
